# Load iframe after clicking hyperlink with progress gif

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm trying to use jquery so that the iframe is empty onPageload, and after I click the happy face hyperlink, it then loads the iframe and shows the loading.gif.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grundysf/E4zeh/2/)

iFrame onload is not loading my div loadImg.

```
<iframe id="myiFrame" scrolling="no" onload="document.getElementById('loadImg').style.display='none';" >
</iframe>
```

Comment: JQuery Mobile has a loading widget that you can  show and hide as you need. Have you looked at that?

Comment: I have not, I will take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Loader for JQuery Mobile: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/loader/

Then your Script would look something like:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $.mobile.loading( "show", {,
            theme: 'd'
    });
    var iframe = $("#myiFrame");
    iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src"));
    iframe.(window).load(function(){
        $.mobile.loading( "hide" );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ' instead of "

```
onload='document.getElementById('loadImg').style.display='none';'
```

Your code should be

```
<iframe id="myiFrame" scrolling="no" onload='document.getElementById('loadImg').style.display='none';' >
</iframe>
```